# Date not resetting to 1970 in x86_64 linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, clock

I want the date to be reset to `1970-01-01` on a x86_64 board (amd carrizo). Kernel is 3.10. I have disabled the `RTC_DRV_CMOS` as well as ntp, but the date gets set automatically somehow. When `RTC_DRV_CMOS` is not enabled, arent we supposed to get the date set to 1970 which is shown in dmesg.

Comment: You have to clarify your question by providing **at least** exact board name and model, kernel version and diff between two *.config* files.

Comment: @0andriy Updated question